# add characters to variable path to load sequence of images

Tags: matlab

im trying to load a sequence of images to matlab and have the whole path saved in a variable "pth" as shown:

```
pth= D:\matlabisfun\dist\
```

and i wanna translated to: 'D:\matlabisfun\dist\'

any ideas ??

Comment: what characters have you added? The quotation marks?

Comment: "Translate" what? Your intended result is apparently the same as the input (I'm assuming the input is a string)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is vague but I will make an attempt.

In MATLAB, if you define: `pth = 'D:\matlabisfun\dist\'`

You basically get: `pth = D:\matlabisfun\dist\`

If you define `pth = {'D:\matlabisfun\dist\'}`

You get: `pth = 'D:\matlabisfun\dist\'`